# Ember JS nested resources: Assertion failed: Cannot call get with 'id' on an undefined object

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

I am stuck on an EmberJS problem for the life of me and simply cannot get my head around it.

What I have is a collection of resources specified as a resource in my Router, like. This in turn, loads another resource which is basically a singular instance of the 'resources collection'.
Essentially my router looks like this:

```
App.Router.map(function(){     
        this.resource('stacks', function(){
                this.resource('stack',{path:'/:stack_id'});
        });
});
```

However, when I visit the /stacks page, I get:

**Assertion failed: Cannot call get with 'id' on an undefined object**

Both Stacks and Stack have a route defined later in the code like 'Ember.Route.extend({})' for each of them and the Stacks route returns the 'stack' model from the data store. Is there something explicitly wrong above here, cause I am following examples and it doesn't look to me that i am doing anything incorrect.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

does your stack model have a property on it called stack_id?  if not, you need to implement a serialize method on the stack route

```
App.StackRoute = Em.Route.extend({

  serialize: function(model){
    return { stack_id: model.get('id')};
  }
});
```

Comment: it's got an 'id' property. I am using 'Fixture' data at the moment

Comment: Then you should be able to add that serialize method to your stack route above.

Comment: that was it, I spent like 2 hours trying to whack my brain and see why it wasn't working. The official templates don't state any of this at all on the 'dynamic segments' docs: 
http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/specifying-a-routes-model/

Comment: It's in the defining your routes section, you were just ahead of the game ;) http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/#toc_dynamic-segments

Comment: this ember game is more like a maze to try and figure out what's up at times, btw, I took off the code inside the 'serialize' function, i.e the return statement and it surprisingly worked. No idea why

Comment: it's because you are overriding the serialize method, so it no longer crashes in their default implementation of the serialize method.  If you were to create a link-to using that model it wouldn't work though, it would create the link as /stacks/undefined.  The serialize hook is used for building the url.  In fact your url right now might be undefined, I'm not sure how you are navigating to that item.